# What does this symbol mean in Excel 365 (SharePoint located)

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint, microsoft-excel-365

[image: imgur]

A couple of people are working on the same file at the same time, sometimes. But what does exactly -1 mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figure out it by myself: it is the result of New Window feature --> View --> New Window. It presents one file in 2 windows and marks each exemplar by this number.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it isn't -1, but just a '-' separator like the one between the people icon and the word *Saved*.

So there is one other person working on the sheet.